# How to get the proguard rules of each dependency?

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

I have a project that depends on some maven lib, after proguard I got the files under package com.xxx kept, but I didn't add the rule in my project proguard files, I must be imported from maven lib. I know there will be a merged proguard file during progurad processure. My question is there a way to hook the processure and prints the separated proguard rules, or how to find which lib imports the rule.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe add your dependencies to the question?

Comment: Have you tried using `consumerProguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'` ?

Comment: @finki What I want is how to find the dependency, rather than which dependency.

Comment: @Shark consumerProguardFile is used for library, my question is to locate the library.

Comment: have you tried turning on the `--verbose` mode so it tells you why it's keeping which files?

Comment: I had the problem too and resolved it. Manually, don't think you can find that out automated. That's why I asked to maybe improve your question with some important details regarding this

Answer (score -1):

Modify your `proguard-project.txt` to include

```
-printconfiguration "build/outputs/mapping/configuration.txt"
```

Trigger proguard run with `./gradlew assembleRelease` and inspect the file. It doesn't always tell which `aar` or `jar` has contributed it though. Maybe create feature request for AGP to make behaviour consistent with `aapt` which prints where every line is coming from.

Comment: I know this config, I wonder whether there is a way to hook the processure so that I can print the proguard rules of each module.